# Using Multiple databases with a common code

Tags: c#, database, data-access-layer, multiple-databases

I just want to be able to store and access data from ACCESS,SQLSERVER,SQLCE,SQLLITE based on the users choice.
Is there a SINGLE library that can help me do this job in c#?

I would like to simply change the connection string and not the code.

Is there any way for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) or [SubSonic](http://wiki.kizoom.com/DotNetDevelopment/ContinuousIntegration) can talk to different types of databases, but they may not support all the databases you list (MS Access in particular doesn't seem to be supported by SubSonic). If you're going to use NHibernate, I'd take a look at [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) as it does away with mapping files that NHibernate depends on. I'm only just getting started with it myself, but it's looking good so far.